# jquery performance Issue in IE8

Tags: jquery, performance, internet-explorer

In my webpage i have used the jquery plugin for freezing the table header while scrolling the content.

reference :
    http://jacky.seezone.net/fixedheader/fixedheader.html

But the Issue is with the performance.
The Jquery Takes around 15- 20 seconds to render the table (when table records > 100 ) in IE
but the same works good in firefox and chrome and it takes 0.4 seconds (when table records > 100 )

can any one please help me regarding the issue related with the performance.

I have Noted where it takes the time. Below it the part of code where it takes around 13 seconds to render in IE

```
var bodyContainer = table.wrap('<div></div>').parent()
    .attr('id', tId + "_body_container")
    .css({
    width: s.width,
    height: s.height,
    overflow: 'auto'
});

//Wrap with an overall container
var tableContainer = bodyContainer.wrap('<div></div>').parent()
    .attr('id', tId + '_table_container')
    .css('position', 'absolute');
```

Comment: which Internet Explorer? Can you make a fiddle?